# Nested RecyclerView with same Objects

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

What is the best way to achieve Nested RecyclerView with Similar Object nested in a List.

```
List<Children>
----List<Children>
  ------List<Children>
```

Should I Inflate layout of sub children or different view type all together?

What is the best way to achieve this?

Layout would be like a drop down:

[image: Nested View]

Answer (score 1):

`ParentRecyclerView` contains `Items` and each `Item` have a `ChildRecyclerView` containing `SubItems`

Comment: Having recyclerview inside another won't be that optimised correct?

Comment: That is commonly used to achieve your design. Don't worry @Dr.aNdRO

Comment: I will try and get back to you on how it performs

Comment: Hope it help! I will wait for the result

Comment: Its fine with the way you told. Child RecyclerView must be set to wrap_content as height and can be dynamically inflated

Comment: Glad to hear that! @Dr.aNdRO